Azure bicep - wait for pending operation
I have a deployment that adds a frontdoor security policy using:
resource secutiy_policies 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/securitypolicies@2022-11-01-preview' 

I am now in the process of adding the same app service to the another region using the Ocoptus deploy 'cloud region' deployment. That approach will create both regions at the same time.
In one region (but not the other), adding the secuity policy fails with the following error:

The requested operation cannot be executed on the entity in the
current state.

I think it's because both app services are updating the security policy at the same time.
Is there a way to wait (or retry) if there is a pending operation?
